# How to filter by property being an empty array?

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-ng-repeat

I have this on ng-repeat

```
<tr ng-repeat="website in websites">
    <td>{{website.url}}</td>
</tr>
```

Each `website` object from `websites` array looks like this:

```
{
  url: "example.com",
  groups: []
}
```

Question: How to apply filter to above loop so that it only shows elements where `groups` property is an empty array?

Things I've tried:

```
data-ng-repeat="website in websites | filter: {groups: []}"
data-ng-repeat="website in websites | filter: !groups.length"
data-ng-repeat="website in websites | filter: groups.length === 0"
```

*(no errors in console but filters out everything)*

```
data-ng-repeat="website in websites | filter: {groups: ''}"
```

*(does the opposite of what I want, and shows only items where `groups` is not an empty array)*

```
data-ng-repeat="website in websites | filter: {groups: null}"
```

*(if instead of [] I use null to signify there's no values, this works, but it seems really messy...because I'd need to constantly look out for `groups` property becoming empty, and setting it to null manually)*

Comment: can you show some data... which you are trying to filter

Comment: Using a predicate function as the filter - http://plnkr.co/edit/cfjIT4Qsbushw3ebu2DD?p=preview

Comment: @entre: each "groups" property is just an array, either empty or containing integers, such as [3,5,6]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I added a filter function in the controller:

JS:

```
angular.module('myApp', [])
  .controller('myController', ['$scope',
    function($scope) {
      $scope.friends = [{
        name: 'John', phone: '555-1276', a: [1, 2, 3]
      }, { name: 'Mary',  phone: '800-BIG-MARY',  a: [1, 2, 3]
      }, { name: 'Mike', phone: '555-4321',  a: null
      }, { name: 'Adam', phone: '555-5678', a: []
      }, { name: 'Julie', phone: '555-8765', a: []
      }, { name: 'Juliette', phone: '555-5678', a: []
      }];

      $scope.filterFn = function(item) {
        // must have array, and array must be empty
        return item.a && item.a.length === 0;
      };

    }
  ]);
```

In your template:

```
<table>
  <tr><th>Name</th><th>Phone</th><th>array len</th></tr>
  <tr ng-repeat="friend in friends | filter: filterFn">
    <td>{{friend.name}}</td>
    <td>{{friend.phone}}</td>
    <td>{{friend.a.length}}</td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

[Modified Angular Filter doc plnkr](http://plnkr.co/edit/3tnl2ArIyfxi4AKz90yr?p=preview)

Answer (score 3):

You could use comparator parameter like this.

```
<tr ng-repeat="website in websites | filter:{groups: []}:true">
    <td>{{website.url}}</td>
</tr>
```

[Angularjs official document](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/filter/filter) describe the meaning of `true`.

> true: A shorthand for function(actual, expected) { return angular.equals(actual, expected)}. This is essentially strict comparison of expected and actual.

[jsfiddle is here.](https://jsfiddle.net/yazaki/6ypupzyp/)

Comment: I don't believe this solution functions.

Comment: Strange, this exact code filters out everything on my end.

Comment: Yes, your fiddle works, but for some reason when pasted into my app it won't work, and it doesn't give any errors either.

Comment: Hi @ipie! thanks for your comment. Do you mean this solution depends on the version of angularjs? @Freelancer Could you let us know your angularjs version ?

Comment: yes.  I tested it in my own fiddle and just adjusted the angular version. It worked when I changed it to 1.2.1 but breaks when I go to 1.3

Comment: I use 1.4.0 so that must be the reason.

Comment: I see. However I couldn't understand the document of 1.4 seems describe `true` option work. Is that the kind of bug?